# Change of quantifiers in the definition of continuity.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, continuity, epsilon-delta

> Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function on $\Bbb{R}$ and $a \in \Bbb{R}$
>
> $\forall \epsilon>0$ we define the set $$S_{\epsilon}=\{\delta>0|\forall x:0<|x-a|<\delta \Rightarrow 0<|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon\}$$
>
> Assume that $\forall \epsilon>0$ we have $S_{\epsilon}=(0,+\infty)$
>
> What can someone conclude about $f(x)$?

I believe that $f$ is constant $f(a)$

Assume that $\exists x_0 \in \Bbb{R}$ such that $|f(x_0)-f(a)|>0$

Put $\epsilon_0=|f(x_0)-f(a)|>0$

Then we have that $S_{\epsilon_0}=(0,+\infty)$

We choose $\delta_0>0$ big enough such that $x_0 \in (a-\delta_0,a+\delta_0)$

Then we can easily see that $\delta_0 \notin S_{\epsilon_0}\Rightarrow S_{\epsilon_0} \neq (0,+\infty)$ which is a contradiction.

Thus $f(x)=f(a), \forall x \in \Bbb{R}$.

Is my proof correct?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Nice..Thank you.:)

Comment: In the definition of S are a and x supposed to be constants?

Comment: Only $a$ is a constant..$x$ is not from hypothesis that $S_{\epsilon}=(0,+\infty)$

Comment: @MariosGretsas.  Then the definition of S is missing a quantifier.